# How to use additional flags when creating lisp script file to start from console

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I want to create a `.lisp` file which I can start as script, i.e., with a leading `#!/bin/usr/sbcl --script`. This works just fine.

File:

```
#!/usr/bin/sbcl --script
(format t "test~%")
```

Output:

```
$> ./test.lisp
test
```

However, I also need to adjust the dynamic space size for that particular script to work. But this somehow prevents the `--script` flag from working

File:

```
#!/usr/bin/sbcl --dynamic-space-size 12000 --script
(format t "test~%")
```

Output:

```
$> ./test.lisp
This is SBCL 1.4.5.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
*
```

**How can I increase the dynamic space size while keeping the convenience of starting the lisp program/script from the command prompt?**

Comment: Are you sure that it is `/bin/usr/sbcl` and not `/usr/bin/sbcl`?

Comment: @Svante thank you for catching that. Doesn't change the underlying question, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general limitation of shebang lines and not SBCL specific.

Newer `env` versions (in GNU — FreeBSD has had this a bit longer) understand a `-S` option to split the argument:

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html#g_t_002dS_002f_002d_002dsplit_002dstring-usage-in-scripts

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S sbcl --dynamic-space-size 9000 --script
```

Comment: sadly my Ubuntu 18.04 does not support `-S`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `#!` considers everything following the command as a single string and thus `--dynamic-space-size 12000 --script` is treated as one and not as a parameter and a flag.

My current solution is to create an additional `.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
sbcl --dynamic-space-size 12000 --script ./test.lisp $@
```

However, this has the obvious downside that the script needs to be started from the same directory as the `.lips` file. Consequently, I am still looking for the 'perfect' solution and this is rather a stop-gap.